# SQL Query returns NULL in PHP but works fine in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Running this code:

```
public function findBooking($start_date, $pitches, $nights, $people, $first_name, $last_name, $email){

    $error = false;
    $bookings = array();

    $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
                   if((!$start_date == '') && (!$nights == '')){
            $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date. ' + ' . ($nights-1) . ' days'));
        } else {
            $end_date = '';
        }

        $find_booking_sql = "SELECT * FROM booking LEFT JOIN camper ON booking.camper_id = camper.camper_id
                             WHERE (start_date LIKE  '%$start_date%')
                             AND (end_date LIKE  '%$end_date%') 
                             AND (pitches LIKE  '%$pitches%') 
                             AND (people LIKE  '%$people%')
                             AND (first_name LIKE  '%$first_name%')
                             AND (last_name LIKE  '%$last_name%')
                             AND (email LIKE  '%$email%')
                             ORDER BY start_date ASC";
        $find_booking_result = $this->db_connection->query($find_booking_sql);
        if ((!$find_booking_result->num_rows == 0)) {  
            // Not run
            }
        } else {
            $error = 'No bookings found';
        }

    }

    return array(
        'bookings' => $bookings,
        'error' => $this->db_connection->error,
        'debug' => $find_booking_sql,
        'result' => $find_booking_result
    );
}
```

returns `current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null` when run in PHP, but if I run the SQL from PHPMyAdmin, it works fine.

I've checked similar questions, but the solutions don't work with this - I've tried removing the 's, and there is only one query being run.

Example generated SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM booking
LEFT JOIN camper ON booking.camper_id = camper.camper_id
WHERE (start_date LIKE '%')
    AND (end_date LIKE '%')
    AND (pitches LIKE '%')
    AND (people LIKE '%')
    AND (first_name LIKE '%')
    AND (last_name LIKE '%') AND (email LIKE '%')
ORDER BY start_date ASC`
```

Comment: For one `email LIKE $email` seems unlikely to work without quotes. Try `echo $find_booking_sql;` and run the output in SQL.

Comment: show  the real query you use in phpadmin

Comment: Edited with a query and quoted the $email variable - I had copied old version of the code

Comment: also share php code, how you are making `$start_date`, `$end_date`, etc ... ?

Comment: this query is working?????? `SELECT * FROM booking LEFT JOIN camper ON booking.camper_id = camper.camper_id WHERE (start_date LIKE '%') AND (end_date LIKE %) AND (pitches LIKE %) AND (people LIKE %) AND (first_name LIKE '%') AND (last_name LIKE '%') AND (email LIKE '%') ORDER BY start_date ASC`

Comment: How can we know what you are really running. You keep changing it. Take a breath, and make sure you are showing US what YOU are really running

Comment: You have to show your full php code and also through `php` only `echo` this query and show us what it `echoed`?

Comment: If your LIKE's are being generated like this `(start_date LIKE '%') ` then it looks like you have not set anything into your `$variables` **Any of them**

Comment: I've edited it with the full context. The arguments are passed from a form that conditional assigns either a % or an escaped value, for example `$start_date = $_POST['start_date'] ? strip_tags($_POST['start_date'], ENT_QUOTES) : '%';`

Comment: Don't play with symbol `%` so much, just use in query like this `LIKE '%$end_date%'` and set blank value for all variables.

Comment: I've updated the code to use '%var%', but the problem is still there. I've also tried `SELECT * FROM booking` by itself, but it hasn't solved it. No error is given by `$this->db_connection->error`, so it's not a connection issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - I was running the PHP query on the live, empty database but the PHPMyAdmin query on the staging database.

I switched the database and the original code worked fine.